# How to configure prod/dev variables in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to use pure TypeScript for my next project, without Webpack.

However, how would I go about defining compile time options?

I want something like:

```
if (DEBUG) {
    ...
}
```

To be compiled down to:

```
if (false) {
    ...
}
```

(which would then be eliminated by the minifier, in production builds)

I would like to be able to swap the flag without changing the source code (setting it from tsconfig.json, in the ENV or from tsc command line).

With Webpack, I used the DefinePlugin for this, but I can't figure out how to do it in TypeScript.

Comment: You won't be able to do that with typescript only. You can write a very simple script that goes over the compiled js and looks for this `DEBUG` and replaces it with `false`.